# Custom Notation in HighChart series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a section in my webpage, in which I show a `HighChart` graph, something as below:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
});
```

[image]

We can see that the points are displayed as `numbers`.
I want that the numbers be replaced by `strings` such as **'3.9%','4.2%'**..and so on.

When I change the data `array` in the above code to include the '%' sign, the chart doesn't render. I guess `HighCharts.js` only allows numbers to be plotted.

How can the custom notation of **'3.9%','4.2%'**.. and so on be shown in the chart?

Experts please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [dataLabels option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.dataLabels) with the good format, like `format: "{point.y} %"`

```
series: [{
  name: 'London',
  data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8],
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    format: "{point.y} %"
  }
}]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. I need to study the HighCharts API in detail.